# Get the DisplayMode Suffix being used by MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP.NET MVC 4 I set the display mode suffix to "CAT":

```
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("CAT")
        {
            ContextCondition = (ctx => some condition)
        });
```

In a child controller I need to know what the suffix it is running under, bascially "CAT"

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult MainMenu(){
           var cat = getthesuffix() ??????
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled-together a solution.

"EnumDisplayModeProvider " is my own enum for the various modes I set the site to.

```
 public EnumDisplayModeProvider GetDisplayModeId()
    {
        foreach (var mode in DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes)
            if (mode.CanHandleContext(HttpContext))
            {
                EnumDisplayModeProvider modeProvider = EnumDisplayModeProvider.generic;
                var id=mode.DisplayModeId;
                Enum.TryParse(id, true, out modeProvider);
                return modeProvider;
            }

        throw new Exception("No display mode");
    }
```